# GroupBy + Condition + Mean()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

suppose we have 3 columns, A-B-C, I need to **group** by "A", but then B needs to be a **range** where B>0 and B<20, and then with that set calculate the **mean** from C.

Can u help me?

tyvm!

Comment: Have you tried anything? There are many panads questions out there ;)

Comment: Do post any code that you have tried, also some example of the dataframe before and after if possible

Comment: df["newmean"] = df.groupby('A')["C"].mean() but I don't know where to set the "B" condition...

Comment: What should be the values in rows where tthe condition of B isn't met?
Also, suppose you have two rows in the same group that match the condition on B, do you want the "newmean" column to have the value twice, once for each?

It would be good to add a small dummy input and expected output explanation

Comment: I've posted a general idea photo down here, sorry Im new around here

Comment: @YamilEzequiel - no problems :) Please edit your question to include the details you posted as an answer

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/OQjCUS0.png, this is the general idea, make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('rows.csv')
temp = []
for val in data['PPV']:
    if val<20:
        temp.append(1)
    elif 20<val and val<40:
        temp.append(2)
    else:
        temp.append(3)
data['temp'] = temp
output = data.groupby(['Responsable', 'temp'])['Yield'].mean()
print(output)
```

You should customize it. You can also do more elegant with [numpy.digitize](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.digitize.html).

Comment: A not optimized version is to loop over your b conditions and then perform like above.

Comment: 1 sec, i need to block it

Comment: http://www.sharecsv.com/s/e69e85b756815a65b7aed60957086008/rows.csv